# Bug with kendo grid,for closing pop up editor,you need to press cancel many times

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

its over a week im dealing with a  strange behavior of kendo grid ,let me split my problem, for better understanding ,i have a autocomplete text box ,after I press ENTER,it binds my grid,when I press "add new record" on my kendo grid,if I press cancel,the pop up will be closed,BUTTT after second search and the add new record,if press cancel,this time needs 2times pressing,3d time needs 3times pressing.......made me crazy,badly need your help

Here is the code

```
    $(document).keypress(function (e) {

        var myResult;
        var modelProducerResult;
        var temp = null;
        var mydata;
        var mydata_deviceType;
        var modelProducerDrpList;
        if (e.which == 13) {
            var i = 0;
            debugger;
            var flag = 0;
            // $('#turbingrid').data().kendoGrid.refresh();
            var drp = document.getElementById('autocomplete').value;
            $.ajax({
                dataType: "json",
                type: "POST",
                url: "@Url.Action("turbineDeviceDetail","AdminTool")",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                data: JSON.stringify({ "turbine": drp, }),

                success: function (result) {
                    //debugger;
                    myResult = result;
                    var flg = "s";
                    $.ajax({
                        dataType: "json",
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "@Url.Action("producersDevice","AdminTool")",
                        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                        data: JSON.stringify({ "flg": flg, }),
                        success: function (data) {
                            //    debugger;
                            mydata = data;
                        }
                    })

                    var flg_dvType = "s";
                    $.ajax({
                        dataType: "json",
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "@Url.Action("deviceTypeList","AdminTool")",
                        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                        data: JSON.stringify({ "flg": flg_dvType, }),
                        success: function (data) {
                            //    debugger;
                            mydata_deviceType = data;

                        }

                    });

                    dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
                        transport: {
                            read: function (options) {
                                options.success(result); // where data is the local data array

                            },

                            create: function (options) {


                                if ($("input[name='DeviceIP']").val() == "" || $("input[name='TurbineId']").val() == "") {
                                    alert("DeviceIP and TurbineID could not be blank ");
                                    $("input[name='DeviceIP']").css("background-color", "red");
                                    $("input[name='TurbineId']").css("background-color", "red");

                                }
                                else


                                    $.ajax({
                                        type: "POST",
                                        url: "@Url.Action("AddDeviceToTurbine","AdminTool")",
                                        data: options.data.models[0],
                                        dataType: "json",
                                        success: function (data) {
                                            options.success(data);
                                            alert("New Device Has Been Inserted");
                                            //var e = $.Event("keypress", { which: 13 });
                                            //$('#autocomplete').trigger(e);


                                        },
                                        //error: function (data) {
                                        //    options.error(data);
                                        //    alert("Insert New Data Has Been Failed");
                                        //    alert(data);

                                        //},
                                        error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                                            alert(xhr.responseText);

                                        }
                                    });

                            },
                            update: function (options) {

                                if ($("input[name='DeviceIP']").val() == "" || $("input[name='TurbineId']").val() == "") {
                                    alert("DeviceIP and TurbineID could not be blank ");

                                    $("input[name='DeviceIP']").css("background-color", "red");
                                    $("input[name='TurbineId']").css("background-color", "red");
                                }
                                else
                                    $.ajax({
                                        type: "POST",
                                        url: "@Url.Action( "update_grid","AdminTool")",
                                        data: options.data.models[0],
                                        dataType: "json",
                                        success: function (data) {
                                            options.success(data);
                                            alert("Update Has Been Done!");
                                            var value = document.getElementById('autocomplete').value;
                                            var e = $.Event("keypress", { which: 13 });
                                            $('#autocomplete').trigger(e);

                                        },
                                        error: function (data) {
                                            options.error(data);
                                            alert("Update Failed!");
                                        },
                                    });


                            },

                            parameterMap: function (options, operation) {
                                if (operation !== "read" && options.models) {
                                    return { models: kendo.stringify(options.models) };
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        batch: true,
                        pageSize: 40,
                        schema: {
                            //data: employee,
                            model: {
                                id: "DeviceIP",
                                fields: {
                                    DeviceIP: { editable: true, nullable: false },
                                    //Producer: { type:"string" },
                                    //3 Model: { type: "string" },
                                    DeviceType: { type: "string" },
                                    Description: { type: "string" },
                                    Username: { type: "string" },
                                    Password: { type: "string" },
                                    PublicIP: { type: "string" },
                                    ModelProducer: { type: "string" },
                                    Model: { type: "string" },
                                    Producer: { type: "string" },
                                    TurbineId: { type: "string" }
                                    //UnitPrice: { type: "number", validation: { required: true, min: 1} },
                                    //Discontinued: { type: "boolean" },
                                    //UnitsInStock: { type: "number", validation: { min: 0, required: true } }
                                }
                            }
                        }


                    });

                    $("#turbingrid").kendoGrid({
                        //   debugger;

                        dataSource: dataSource,
                        scrollable: false,

                        //toolbar: ["create"],
                        toolbar: [
                                 {
                                     name: "create",
                                     text: "ADD NEW DEVICE"
                                 }
                        ],

                        columns: [
                                 { field: 'DeviceIP', title: 'DeviceIP', width: '100px', id: 'DeviceIP' },
                                 { field: 'Producer', title: 'Producer', width: '80px', id: 'Producer' },//editor: ProductNameDropDownEditor,
                                 { field: 'Model', title: 'Model', width: '220px', id: 'Model' },
                                // { field: 'DeviceType', title: 'DeviceType', width: '100px', id: 'DeviceType', editor: deviceTypesList },
                                 { field: 'Description', title: 'Description', width: '220px' },
                                 { field: 'Username', title: 'Username', width: '120px' },
                                 { field: 'Password', title: 'Password', width: '100px' },
                                 { field: 'PublicIP', title: 'PublicIP', width: '120px', id: 'PublicIP' },
                                 { field: 'TurbineId', title: 'TurbineId', width: '120px', id: 'TurbineId', hidden: true },
                                 { field: 'device_id', title: 'device_id', width: '120px', id: 'deviceid', hidden: true },
                               //  { field: 'ModelProducer', title: 'Producer/Model', id: 'ModelProducer', hidden: true, editor: modelPro },
                                 {
                                     command: ["edit"], title: "&nbsp;"

                                 }
                        ],




                        editable: "popup",

                    });
                }
            })
        }
    });


    //This Part Is For The AUTOCOMPLETE textbox

    $(document).ready(function () {
        var value = document.getElementById('autocomplete').value;
        $.ajax({
            dataType: "json",
            type: "POST",
            url: "@Url.Action("List_Turbine","AdminTool")",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            //data: JSON.stringify({ "name": value ,}),
            data: {},
            success: function (result) {
                $("#autocomplete").kendoAutoComplete({
                    dataSource: result,
                    dataTextField: "Text",


                    // filter: "contains"

                });


            }
        })

    });
```

Comment: Could be that your requests have not completed before you shut down the windows (It's a possibility). Check the network tab in Dev Tools to determine any on-going requests.

Comment: @Adriani6 the problem is,every time I bind my grid and press add new record,seems it adds additional pop up,then when I want to close,i need to close them one by one

Comment: then make sure, in your dialogue open function the previous dialogue is removed from DOM, $(<Dialogue>).html("");, then you'll know it is not there. I believe you do bind the window to a DOM element?

Comment: @Adriani6 can you please tell me where I should write it? fortunately you understood my problem

Comment: Write that on the click handler which opens your dialogue, right at the top. I found out that fixing stuff in kendo relies on observation of models, data types, requests and what is already binded unfortunately.

Comment: @Adriani6 you mean when I press cancel in the pop up editor,it should destroy the dialog?should I write additional function?

Comment: You can either do it on close or you can do it when you open the dialogue. How you do it is up to you, you're the one writing the code, whatever makes more sense to you.

Comment: @Adriani6 can please tell me the function for destroy the pop up after pressing cancel,i cant find it really

Comment: I can't. Its not in the provided code. I don't know where you open/close events are. I provided you with code to clear the DOM already.

Comment: I added ("grid").empty in the beginning and now it works!thanks for all the hints

Comment: If you've found an answer to your own question, you should post an answer below. This will allow you to mark your question as "resolved" and indicate that you're no longer waiting for an answer.